# Errors when update

Tags: 18.04, grub2, upgrade, lts

I wanted to manually do:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and I have errors at the end:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Content of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID="ef1f8271-5d94-4706-9904-61c9cd7da3ba"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Have you made changes to `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: No, I have another OS, but I don't think that I edit grub myself. That is why I am asking as I don't want to make mess and not have access to any of OS. Thanks.

Comment: Please add contents of `/etc/default/grub`  to the question.

Comment: It looks like the file was edited in Windows.

Comment: No, i just open it under Ubuntu in edit mode on Double Commander

Comment: You have an unclosed quote in `"quiet splash resume=UUID="ef1f8271-5d94-4706-9904-61c9cd7da3ba"` Remove the second quote.

Comment: So it must look like this ? : "quiet splash resume=UUID="ef1f8271-5d94-4706-9904-61c9cd7da3ba

Comment: I don't think that is a problem as they are four altogether: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID="ef1f8271-5d94-4706-9904-61c9cd7da3ba"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: @Pilot6 - you were right!!!

Answer (score 0):

Line should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=ef1f8271-5d94-4706-9904-61c9cd7da3ba"
```

That solve the problem.
Thanks @Pilot6